# $_SERVER[“DOCUMENT_ROOT”] is blank but phpinfo shows correct value. php7

Tags: apache, xampp, wamp, php

php 7.3.6 xampp

if i check with phpinfo

$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT] is set with c:\xampp\htdocs

if check with c:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf

DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"

```
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

but while making

```
echo $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"];
```

it shows blank.

what seems problem? any alternative solution? how i can set this?

```
array(49) {
  ["ALLUSERSPROFILE"]=>
  string(14) "C:\ProgramData"
  ["APPDATA"]=>
  string(29) "C:\Users\ABCD\AppData\Roaming"
  ["CommonProgramFiles"]=>
  string(29) "C:\Program Files\Common Files"

  string(22) "C:\Users\ABCD\OneDrive"
  ["OS"]=>
  string(10) "Windows_NT"
  ["Path"]=>
  string(217) "C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;C:\xampp\php\;C:\Users\ABCD\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;"
  ["PATHEXT"]=>
  string(53) ".COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC"
  ["SystemRoot"]=>
  string(10) "C:\Windows"
  ["USERPROFILE"]=>
  string(13) "C:\Users\ABCD"
  ["windir"]=>
  string(10) "C:\Windows"
  ["PHP_SELF"]=>
  string(46) "C:\xampp\htdocs\xxx.php"
  ["PATH_TRANSLATED"]=>
  string(46) "C:\xampp\htdocs\xxx.php"
  ["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT"]=>
  float(1560058600.7734)
  ["REQUEST_TIME"]=>
  int(1560058600)
  ["argv"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(46) "C:\xampp\htdocs\xxx.php"
  }
  ["argc"]=>
  int(1)
}
```

here is output of vardump

Comment: Please post results of `var_dump($_SERVER)`

Comment: post edited with var_dump($_SERVER) with trimmed fields.. @mulquin

Comment: It appears that you are running this script from the command line. PHP run through CLI does not populate the DOCUMENT_ROOT variable. Try running through your web browser.

Comment: it is observed that if i tries in xampp5x then it is ok in both CLI and Browser.  but in xampp7 its not working in CLI and Browser..